# signalr stockticker example not working - javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

i have downloaded the signalr stockticker example from the nuget packages, but it doesnt work! the error message i get when running stockticker.html through visual studio debug is

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'client': object is null or undefined

Do i need to do anything for this demo to work straight away??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because you need to add a visual studio web application, not website.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the version number in the reference to the SignalR JS file in StockTicker.html is the same as the version number of the SignalR JS file in the Scripts folder.  Also, see the tutorial for this sample on the asp.net site at

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr

Comment: I have checked the javascript references already. am I right to believe I just simply have to create a new visual studio empty web site, and add the web source files & make sure the scripts location match, and it should then run right?

Comment: Right.  Install the package in a new empty web site, set the .html file as the start page, and run the project.